# How to retrieve Album Art from .mp3 file using MediaMetadataRetriever()

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to retrieve Album Art from MP3 file but the following code isn't working. Whenever the application starts it shows me Gray color box (check code in try/catch block).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    byte[] art;
    ImageView album_art;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getInit();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);


        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

        cursor.close();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(url);

        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();

            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);

            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }

    public void getInit() {

        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.album_art);

    }

}
```

I also tried using cursor for getting Album Art but it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `NullPointerException`

```
art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
```

MediaMetadataRetriever document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#getembeddedpicture):

> Call this method after setDataSource(). This method finds the optional
>   graphic or album/cover art associated associated with the data source.
>   If there are more than one pictures, (any) one of them is returned.

The byte array returned is `null` if not found so you have to check for null before decode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Album art for `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

You need to use `Uri uri =  MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`